# No suitable driver found for while connecting to Athena using JDBC

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jdbc, amazon-athena

I am trying to connect to Athena using a JDBC connection with Java.

I am able to connect when I run the code through eclipse. But I am unable to connect when I run a Spring-Boot application, that runs on EMR cluster in AWS.

Below is the code snippet.

Pom.xml- Tried 2 dependencies separately

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.syncron.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>simba-athena-jdbc-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>AthenaJDBC41</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1-atlassian-hosted</version>
    </dependency>
```

Code Snippet-

```
Properties dbProps = new Properties();
        dbProps.put(USER, props.getProperty(AWS_EMR_ACCESS_KEY_ID));
        dbProps.put(PASSWORD, props.getProperty(AWS_EMR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID));
        dbProps.put(S3_STAGING_DIR_KEY, props.getProperty(S3_STAGING_DIR_VALUE));
        dbProps.put(AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER_KEY,props.getProperty(AWS_CREDENTIALS_PROVIDER_VALUE));
        //dbProps.put(DRIVER, props.getProperty(ATHENA_DRIVER));

        Class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");
        //Class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");


        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(props.getProperty(ATHENA_URL), dbProps);
```

Below is the error

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for "jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:443/"
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything else looks good to me, but in my case I have used `com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver` for `AWS` `Athena` `jdbc` connection.

In my case, It was `Class.forName("com.simba.athena.jdbc.Driver");` instead of `Class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");`

I have used  [AthenaJDBC41-2.0.9.jar](https://athena-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/drivers/JDBC/SimbaAthenaJDBC_2.0.9/AthenaJDBC41_2.0.9.jar).
I'm less sure about the `maven` `dependencies` that you are using. I just downloaded and added it from local repository.

Hope it helps and let me know if you have further questions.